# Displaying frames properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I am developing a game in JavaScript. I have organized all the parts of the game in different JavaScript files. So, this is the Player.js file, every time I run this in my browser ( run from a html file of course), I come into this problem where the Player object flickers from a image to a transparent rectangle: heres the code:

```
function Player() {
this.frames = [];
this.right = true;
this.currentFrame = 0;
this.currentAction = "WALKING";
this.image = new Image();
this.x = 0;
this.y = 0;

this.setPosition = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};
this.setVector = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
};
this.setAction = function(action) {
    this.currentAction = action;
};
this.setRight = function(bool) {
    this.right = bool;
}
this.draw = function(context) {
    if(this.right == true) {
        if(this.currentAction == "WALKING") {
            this.frames = [ "res/playerRight.png" ];
        }
    } else if(this.right == false) {
        if(this.currentAction == "WALKING") {
            this.frames = [ "res/playerLeft.png" ];
        }
    }
    if(this.currentFrame < this.frames.length) {
        this.currentFrame += 1;
        this.image.src = this.frames[this.currentFrame - 1];
        context.drawImage(this.image, this.x,
            this.y, 32, 32);
    } else {
        this.currentFrame = 0;
    }
};
```

}

heres some images of what it does:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RcOC.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxbNY.png

Comment: That might be because the image is not ready when you load it.

Comment: The image was loaded, if the object loads the image itself, the image is automatically loaded cause the main javascript file calls the object. If it was in the case that the image was not loaded, then the image wouldn't display at all.

Comment: @UnhandyFir9: If the image was not loaded then the browser would download the image and THEN display it which is why you see the flicker - the browser needs to draw something but it's still waiting for the image file to arrive from the net.

Comment: @slebetman The image is not online, it's local. I get what you mean, but I think the flicker has something to do with the frame rate: at the setInterval(), I have setInterval(draw, 1000 / 5); I changed it to setInterval(draw, 1000 / 30); and it flickers faster.

Comment: Wait, this part doesn't make any sense at all: `this.frames=[ "res/playerRight.png" ]`. Why would you make an array that only has one element?

Comment: This is for testing purposes, I am seeing how this object will react with the other code, thats why it only has one element.

Comment: I've added other images before, and it shows basicly this, "image1, image2, blank, image1, image2, blank, image1, image2, AND SO ON"

Comment: "if X is true... else if X is false..." What else is it going to be? Fish?

Answer (score 0):

How about you preload all the images and you choose the correct one in your condition. Currently everytime you set the source the image is reloaded, and you are drawing it before it is ready.

```
// you can improve this part for your needs
var image1Loaded = false;
var image2Loaded = false;

this.preLoadImages = function (){
    this.image1.onload = function (){
         image1Loaded = true;
    }
    this.image2.onload = function (){
         image2Loaded = true;
    }
    this.image1.src = "res/playerRight.png";
    this.image2.src = "res/playerLeft.png";
}
```

now you can use the images directly in your draw method:

```
this.draw = function(context) {
    var currentImage = "image1";
    if(this.right == true) {
        if(this.currentAction == "WALKING") {
            currentImage = "image1";
        }
    } else if(this.right == false) {
        if(this.currentAction == "WALKING") {
             currentImage = "image2";
        }
    }
    if(this.currentFrame < this.frames.length) {
        this.currentFrame += 1;
        var image = this[currentImage];
        context.drawImage(image, this.x,
            this.y, 32, 32);
    } else {
        this.currentFrame = 0;
    }
};
```

Just make sure your images are already loaded before using them to draw on the canvas

Comment: The image is already preloaded. That's why it actually displays on the screen. I know how Javascript Objects work, I've just never worked with a array of image sources before, but I have seen someone do it. I just can't remember who and I can't remember how to completely do it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but you are using this in your code: `this.image.src = '...'` and this reloads your image once again, and that is why you image is not displayed

Comment: How about I make a array of Image() 's and set the sources separately before i call them. Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bug:

```
if(this.currentFrame < this.frames.length) {
    this.currentFrame += 1;
    context.drawImage(); // <---------------- draw an image
} else {
    this.currentFrame = 0; // <-------------- draw nothing!
}
```

So, let's run through this logic shall we. At the moment, frame length is 1.

```
currentFrame = 0
    so we increment currentFrame
    we draw the image

currentFrame = 1
    currentFrame is not less than frames.length
    we do not draw anything
    we set current frame to 0

currentFrame = 0
    so we increment currentFrame
    we draw the image

repeat....
```

Result: flicker! If frame length is 2 it will flicker 33% of the time, if the frame length is 3 it will flicker 25% of the time etc.

The correct way to handle this:

```
this.currentFrame += 1;
if(this.currentFrame >= this.frames.length) {
    this.currentFrame = 0;
}
this.image.src = this.frames[this.currentFrame]; // **
context.drawImage();

// **note: no need for -1 because currentFrame here is always
//         less than frame.length
```

Or, if you're mathematical:

```
this.currentFrame = (this.currentFrame + 1) % this.frames.length;
this.image.src = this.frames[this.currentFrame];
context.drawImage();
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! I haven't tried this EXACTLY yet, but I read what you said, and I changed my code and it works with no flicker. Thankyou SOOOO much!